# How to work with .bin files

Tags: lubuntu, java, files

I want to install JDK 1.6 on my Lubuntu OS.

But it is some specific `.bin` file instead of `tar.gs` for linux - [Java SE Development Kit 6u45](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html#jdk-6u45-oth-JPR).

**UPDATE:**

After following suggestion, I catch next:

```
error: Failed dependencies:
    /bin/basename is needed by jdk-2000:1.6.0_45-fcs.x86_64
    /bin/cat is needed by jdk-2000:1.6.0_45-fcs.x86_64
    /bin/cp is needed by jdk-2000:1.6.0_45-fcs.x86_64
    /bin/gawk is needed by jdk-2000:1.6.0_45-fcs.x86_64
    /bin/grep is needed by jdk-2000:1.6.0_45-fcs.x86_64
    /bin/ln is needed by jdk-2000:1.6.0_45-fcs.x86_64
    /bin/ls is needed by jdk-2000:1.6.0_45-fcs.x86_64
    /bin/mkdir is needed by jdk-2000:1.6.0_45-fcs.x86_64
    /bin/mv is needed by jdk-2000:1.6.0_45-fcs.x86_64
    /bin/pwd is needed by jdk-2000:1.6.0_45-fcs.x86_64
    /bin/rm is needed by jdk-2000:1.6.0_45-fcs.x86_64
    /bin/sed is needed by jdk-2000:1.6.0_45-fcs.x86_64
    /bin/sort is needed by jdk-2000:1.6.0_45-fcs.x86_64
    /bin/touch is needed by jdk-2000:1.6.0_45-fcs.x86_64
    /usr/bin/cut is needed by jdk-2000:1.6.0_45-fcs.x86_64
    /usr/bin/dirname is needed by jdk-2000:1.6.0_45-fcs.x86_64
    /usr/bin/expr is needed by jdk-2000:1.6.0_45-fcs.x86_64
    /usr/bin/find is needed by jdk-2000:1.6.0_45-fcs.x86_64
    /usr/bin/tail is needed by jdk-2000:1.6.0_45-fcs.x86_64
    /usr/bin/tr is needed by jdk-2000:1.6.0_45-fcs.x86_64
    /usr/bin/wc is needed by jdk-2000:1.6.0_45-fcs.x86_64
    /bin/sh is needed by jdk-2000:1.6.0_45-fcs.x86_64
rpm: RPM should not be used directly install RPM packages, use Alien instead!
rpm: However assuming you know what you are doing...
error: Failed dependencies:
    /bin/sh is needed by sun-javadb-core-10.6.2-1.1.i386
```

How can I unpack and use this `.bin` file to unpack JDK?

Comment: Are you trying to install a rpm. package?

Comment: after run `./jdk-6u45-linux-x64-rpm.bin`, then `sudo rpm -ivh jdk-6u45-linux-amd64.rpm --nodigest`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Make your file executable using :

  `chmod a+x <your_file>.bin`
- Now run it using :

  `./<your_file>.bin`

Comment: I updated question

Comment: I think you are using rpm , use only  the bin file, not rpm.

Comment: what about `rpm.bin`? You are right I checked it was really file extension.

Comment: A `.bin` file is a shell script and an `rpm.bin` is a shell script to install an rpm in Red Hat and Fedora. So use `.bin` not `rpm.bin`